# PHP mail() headers, two to headers problem

Tags: php, email

This might be a dumb question but if I leave `$to = ''` in `mail($to,...)` and put `$to` to mail headers `'to' => '<some@mail.address>'`, might this cause this effect(two 'to' headers)?:

```
To:
Subject: 123
From: <>
To: <some@mail.address>
```

Comment: *blinks* too many tos/twos/toos :X

Answer (score 2):

Never really bothered to look at exactly how mail() behaves until now, just cracked out Wireshark and tried a couple of things and here is the result:

---

### Test1

Message sends; To: header appears before From:

```
mail('person.a@domain.tld','Subject','Body',"From: person.b@domain.tld");
```

### Test2

Message sends; To: header appears after From:

```
mail('person.a@domain.tld','Subject','Body',"From: person.b@domain.tld\r\nTo: person.a@domain.tld");
```

### Test 3

Message wont send; PHP tries to do it but doesn't send an RCPT command, just skips straight to DATA which is a protocol violation so the server tells PHP to go away.

```
mail('','Subject','Body',"From: person.b@domain.tld\r\nTo: person.a@domain.tld");
```

### Test 4

Message sends; both To: headers appear in the order they were specified in $additional_headers, after From:

```
mail('person.a@domain.tld','Subject','Body',"From: person.b@domain.tld\r\nTo: person.a@domain.tld\r\nTo: person.c@domain.tld");
```

### Test 5

Message sends; To: header appears after From: and has the value specified in $additional_headers

```
mail('person.a@domain.tld','Subject','Body',"From: person.b@domain.tld\r\nTo: person.c@domain.tld");
```

---

So it appears that the To: header(s) specified in $additional_headers will override the one auto-generated by PHP from the value of $to, but you will never get multiple To: headers unless you explicitly set them in $additional_headers.

Tested on PHP 5.2.17/win32

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `to` addresses, if that's what you mean:

```
mail('test@example.com;example@test.com',...);
```

Comment: The thing is if I leave in mail function mail('',...) and put 'to' to header, can this cause 2 'to' effect?